# database is locked in R

Tags: sql, r, sqlite

In R, i am using the following function,which uses 3 or 4 database operation within that function. But an error message is displaying like this:

```
Error in sqliteExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (RS_SQLite_exec: could not execute1: database is locked)
```

What modification i need to make in my code? my code is as follows:

```
library('RSQLite')
test <- function(portfolio,date,frame){
  lite <- dbDriver("SQLite", max.con = 25)
  db <- dbConnect(lite, dbname = "portfolioInfo1.db")
  sql <- paste("SELECT *  from ", portfolio," where portDate='", date, "' ", sep = "")
  res <- dbSendQuery(db, sql)
  data <- fetch(res)
  frame1 <- data.frame(portDate=date,frame)

 lite <- dbDriver("SQLite", max.con = 25)
 db <- dbConnect(lite, dbname = "portfolioInfo1.db")
  sql <- paste("delete from ", portfolio," where portDate='", date, "' ", sep = "")
 res <- dbSendQuery(db, sql)

  lite <- dbDriver("SQLite", max.con = 25)
  db <- dbConnect(lite, dbname = "portfolioInfo1.db")
  dbWriteTable(db,portfolio,frame1,append=TRUE,row.names=FALSE) 
}
tick <- c("AAPL","TH","YHOO")
quant <- c("121","1313","131313131")
frame <-data.frame(ticker=tick,quantities=quant)
#print(frame)
test("RUSEG","2006-02-28",frame)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that you connect several times to the same database without disconnecting. Probably the database goes into a lock if a connection is made to prevent anyone else from editing a database which is already being edited.

Either disconnect after each connect, or simply connect once, perform all the queries, and than finally disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

More precisely, multiple processes can read an SQLite database file simultaneously, but only one process at a time can write: [SQLite documentation, File Locking](https://sqlite.org/lockingv3.html#locking)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using the DB Browser to add the table. I didn't save the changes, that's why trying to connect in RStudio (Shiny) did not work.

Comment: I am sorry, but can you explain, why this could not be an answer? Was just trying to help.

Comment: Oh whoops! Sorry; I read that incorrectly. I read it as "It didn't save the changes [...]" and in that case your answer didn't look like an answer (as in solution) to me but just as statement how to achieve the same error. I retracted my flag and removed the comment. Sorry again; I was already through 50 posts or so and it looks like my attention dropped a little :)